# YUIDocs parse Polymer element

Tags: javascript, documentation, polymer, yuidoc

I am attempting to document a series of Polymer web components.  I have used [Polymer/core-docs-viewer](https://github.com/Polymer/core-doc-viewer) in the past but find it is not as complete and extendable as YUIDocs or others like JSDocs.  YUIDocs seems a better choice for documenting larger projects / frontend and backend code to create a single maintainable doc source.

Is there a way to get YUIDocs to parse script blocks inside HTML comment blocks or within the `<script>` tag of a custom element?

I've tried:

```
<!--
/**
* Description
*
*@class kiosk-pager
*@constructor
*/
-->

<polymer-element name="kiosk-pager" attributes="settings pagingRate pageDelay pollRate autoPaging "> //etc
```

also:

```
<polymer-element name="kiosk-pager" attributes="settings pagingRate pageDelay pollRate autoPaging ">
//template
<script>
    /**
    * Description
    *
    *@class kiosk-pager
    *@constructor
    */
```

So far YUIDocs hasn't found and added my class declaration in above comments.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how I am using it with Polymer

```
<script>
/**
    Description of element

        <myelement>I am a sweet custom element</myelement>

    @class myelement
**/
/**
    A description of a property

    @attribute property name
**/
</script>

<dom-module id="myelement">
    Put all of your element's code here
</dom-module>

<script src="./i_keep_the_js_seperate.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a related issue. Your idea are welcome.

https://github.com/yui/yuidoc/issues/328